# Showing that a group G is cyclic IFF $\bar{G}$ is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi$ be an isomorphism from a group G to a group $\bar{G}$

I tried to approach this using the fact that

> Fact: $|a|=|\phi(a)|$ for any element a in a group G.

$\space$ 
Suppose that the order of the element $a$ is n.

Then, $\left \langle a \right \rangle=\left \{ e,a,\cdot \cdot \cdot a^{n-1} \right \}$.

since $\phi \left ( a \right )$ has order n too.

$\left \langle \phi \left ( a \right ) \right \rangle=\left \{ e,\phi\left ( a \right ),\cdot \cdot \cdot , \phi^{n-1} \left ( a \right )\right \}$

If I can show that the group G and $\bar{G}$ is indeed the group generated by the element a and a under the map $\phi$, we are done.

I'm missing something subtle. Any hints?

Edit: Lagrange's theorem would have solved this easily but let's avoid that.

Comment: What is $\overline G$?  What does it mean to be "cyclic under an isomorphism"?

Comment: @lulu The previous title was sloppy. I've made the changes.

Comment: You do not appear to be assuming that $G$ is finite, so you can't necessarily speak of the order, $n$, of an element.  Still, you should be able to prove that, if $g$ generates $G$, then $\phi(g)$ generates $\overline G$.

Comment: I presume G must be of finite order for this to make any sense. It is easy to show that the image of g under the map generates a cyclic group. I know that g of order n indeed generates the set in the OP. But how can I be sure that that also generates the group G?

Comment: There is no need to suppose that $G$ is finite (the result holds for $G=\mathbb Z$).  Say $G$ is cyclic, with $G=<g>$.  Choose $h\in \overline G$.  Then we know there is some $g_1\in G$ such that $\phi(g_1)=h$.  But $g_1=g^k$ for some $k$ so $\phi(g)^k=h$ and we are done.

Comment: This is more a general hint: A group isomorphism has the nice attribute, that all the informations and properties were transmitted from one group to the other.

Comment: As a corollary: If $a$ is a generator of $G$, then $\phi(a)$ is a generator of $\overline{G}$. The converse is also true. But it's important, that we have a group isomorphism.

Comment: It is now clear. Thank you.

Comment: @lulu May I add that this is closely related to the fact that Isomorphism maps generators to generators?